# Query to find member name and score

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one for members having fields as id , name 
Second table as results with fields as rid , mid (member id foreign key), pid , score

I need to show name of member and their score where pid=$id
My query is :

```
$sel = mysql_query("SELECT m.name,r.score FROM member m, score r WHERE m.id=r.mid and r.pid='$id'");
<?php $i=0; while( $sql = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sel )) { ?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php $i++; echo $i; ?> </td>
<td align="center"><?php echo ucfirst( $sql['name'] ); ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $sql['score']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

But no records are getting output.

There are matching records but it is not entering in while loop.

Comment: `FROM member m`? Is that valid?

Comment: "m" it's an alias for "member"...

Comment: @Huey: you can define the table name shorter, what is better for long queries.

Comment: you can also write it as member AS m

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that syntax for an alias. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use as:

`$sel = mysql_query("SELECT m.name as name, r.score as score FROM member m, score r WHERE m.id=r.mid and r.pid='$id'");`

Or so, if you do not want to use as:

`<?php echo ucfirst( $sql['m.name'] ); ?>`

Comment: Anyother way to get name from member table and their score from result table?
Pid is paper id for which results of members are to be shown

Comment: Try to execute a query which is expected to return something via phpMyAdmin/Adminer and look for any results.